# How to create a file and to give it name at the same time

Tags: file

I am having a problem with this C code. I am creating a file and I want to give it a name at the same time. But something is not working - it won´t create this file with the chosen name. The rest of the code works fine btw.

```
FILE *InputRef;                                            

char outputFilename[];                   // Creates a char
printf("Enter the name of your file");   // It asks for a name
outputFilename=getchar();   // And here I want to enter the file name

InputRef = fopen(outputFilename, "w"); //
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was wrong with the code posted above. When getting the file name, one should use gets() instead of fgets().

So instead of writing:

```
fgets(outputFilename, MAXVAL, stdin);
```

one should write:

```
gets(outputFilename);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code,the array declaration should contain size of the array like char outputFilename[36] and getchar() is used to read only one character,try using gets(outputFileName)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXVAL 100

void main()
{
    FILE *InputRef;         
    char outputFilename[MAXVAL];


    printf("Enter the name of your file");
    fgets(outputFilename, MAXVAL, stdin);

   InputRef = fopen(outputFilename, "w")) ;

}
```

Comment: Hi anudeepks, I tried your code and it seems to work until the last line, where it acctually tries to open/create the file. There seems to be some problem with reading the "char outputFilename" Do you know why?

Comment: When I run the program I can print out what I write (the file name). But still the fopen command can´t open and create the file with the name I enter.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, a few words of explanation would go a long way to making this answer valuable to future readers.